# How to remove elements from an Ember.ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

In JavaScript, one can remove selected elements from an array by traversing it in reverse order and using `splice(index, 1)` to remove undesired elements. I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing in Ember.js (without Ember Data).

I have an ArrayController and the associated Route's `model` function simply returns a JavaScript array. There an action in the controller, along the following lines:

```
removeElements: function () {
  var i, arr = this.get('content'),
    i = arr.length;

  while (i) {
    i -= 1;
    if (arr[i].get('flag')) {
      array.replace(i, 1);
  }
}
```

This first appears to work in the browser. For example, if I have three elements and mark the first and third to be removed, the browser will leave the second item displayed.  However, if I later try to mark the latter, Ember complains with `Uncaught Error: Can't remove an item that has never been added.`

I used `replace()` because Ember arrays don't have a `splice` method, but the docs also say that `replace` *must* be implemented in order to be used, but I don't quite understand where I'm supposed to implement it and I haven't found any sample implementations to guide me.

I've also tried various other methods, such as `removeObject`, `removeObjects` and more, but none did what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to create your own array collection and implement replace on that collection (probably extending Ember.Array to get you started).

`removeObject` should work just fine (granted a little inefficient, though if the size of this list is small it's negligible):

```
removeElements: function () {
  var controller = this,
      list = this.toArray();

  list.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.get('flag')){
      controller.removeObject(item);
    }
  });
}
```

using `removeAt` should give you the results you're looking for

```
removeElements: function () {
  var i = this.get('length');

  while (i--) {
    if (this.objectAt(i).get('flag')) {
      this.removeAt(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see what I did wrong when I tried `removeObject`: I didn't use `toArray()`, which I assume makes a copy so that you don't trample on what you're traversing.

Comment: Yes, yes, manipulating a collection whilst iterating said collection is a fun gotcha that isn't quite as apparent in javascript.

Comment: I was still getting `Uncaught Error: Can't remove an item that has never been added.` in my larger app, but it appears that is due to an unrelated problem (a UI element to set multiple flags).